# How to add dependencies to 3rd party library using nexus/maven

Tags: maven-3, nexus, m2eclipse

i'm trying to use Nexus + m2eclipse/maven-3 professionnally, and i've got a huge 3rd party library that needs a lot of dependencies.

Is there any ways to ease my pain by uploading to Nexus this third party library with all its dependencies linked, so that anyone who would need it would just have to add the maven-dependency-tag only for this huge library ?

Do i need to create the pom myself ?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any ways to ease my pain by uploading to Nexus this third party library with all its dependencies linked, so that anyone who would need it would just have to add the maven-dependency-tag only for this huge library?

I'm not aware of such a facility.

> Do I need to create the pom myself ?

I would not create the POM for the thirdparty dependency but I would indeed [consolidate dependencies in a single POM project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps) (and upload it to Nexus).

Comment: but assuming that my dependency needs other 3rd party dependencies, i need to upload them one by one, and then create the POM project to consolidate them into one single dependency (that can be dealt with).
Is that right ?

Comment: @ssaboum: That's what I would do at least.

Answer (score 3):

For future visitors, I was able to add a dependency to a 3rd party artifact within nexus, if you wish to do it this way. I followed the following steps:

1. Create the pom file you want for the 3rd party dependency (I
   downloaded the existing, auto-generated pom in nexus, then added the
   dependency that I wanted).
2. Delete the pom file and it's friends (the SHA1 and MD5 files). I did
   this through the UI.
3. Upload the pom file through the artifact upload tab, using the same
   GAV information, with the artifact type being a pom file.
4. Celebrated that it was this straightforward.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Especially step 4 seemed to be crucial in the whole process.