# Set transitive dependencies for custom library

Tags: maven, transitive-dependency

We are using nexus as local maven repository manager and adding our custom developed libraries there via web UI. Some of our custom developed libraries depends on other self developed libraries. If I add dependency to my pom I also want transitive library to be downloaded. I wonder to know how can I do it ? I don't want to add second library to POM file.
Thanks

Comment: If your libraries are all correctly Mavenized then the transitive part should be handled already, that's the point of Maven.

Comment: does this mean ` adding our custom developed libraries there via web UI` not using maven to deploy those lib to nexus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add dependencies to 3rd party library using nexus/maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043969/how-to-add-dependencies-to-3rd-party-library-using-nexus-maven)

Comment: Yes, maven was not used to deploy those libraries to repository. I 've deployed them via UI.

Comment: What does "via ui" mean? The issue is whether or not those libraries correctly identify their dependencies.

Comment: Dave, I've solved issue as indicated Joe. via UI means that I've did it via nexus admin interface

Comment: I've solved my issue via 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043969/how-to-add-dependencies-to-3rd-party-library-using-nexus-maven

Thanks everbody